# Как убрать отступы между виджетом и окном приложения QT

Tags: qt, qwidget

[image: Картинка]
Как убрать отступы, помеченные красными стрелками?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна функция `void QLayout::setContentsMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`, выставляющая отступы по краям компоновщика.